# How to setup a product that has multiple price options?

Tags: plugins

Still very new to the Woocommerce interface. I'm trying to figure out how to sell 'attendance' to a workshop. So I'm assuming I need to create a 'variable product' and then  I need to add the following 2 price options:

- 1 attendant:  $125
- 2 attendants: $195

The gateway is paypal

> WooCommerce version   1.6.5.1
>
> WordPress version WP 3.4.1

Comment: A quick Google search -> http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/user-guide/product-variations/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll need to set this as variable product.
After selecting variable product, go to attributes.
Name it - for instance - Number of Attendants.
Then in the values area enter - 1 attendant: $125|2 attendants: $195

At this point, press publish.

Then select the variables tab and click on the items - 1 attendant - or - 2 attendants - to drop down the options and set the pricing.

Save your changes and you'll have a dropdown selection box that will appear on your product page. The "add to cart" button will appear when one of these options is selected.

Hope this is helpful.